# lapply and do.call running very slowly?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, do.call

I have a data frame that is some 35,000 rows, by 7 columns. it looks like this:

> head(nuc)

```
  chr feature    start      end   gene_id    pctAT    pctGC length
1   1     CDS 67000042 67000051 NM_032291 0.600000 0.400000     10
2   1     CDS 67091530 67091593 NM_032291 0.609375 0.390625     64
3   1     CDS 67098753 67098777 NM_032291 0.600000 0.400000     25
4   1     CDS 67101627 67101698 NM_032291 0.472222 0.527778     72
5   1     CDS 67105460 67105516 NM_032291 0.631579 0.368421     57
6   1     CDS 67108493 67108547 NM_032291 0.436364 0.563636     55
```

gene_id is a factor, that has about 3,500 unique levels. I want to, for each level of gene_id get the `min(start)`, `max(end)`, `mean(pctAT)`, `mean(pctGC)`, and `sum(length)`.

I tried using lapply and do.call for this, but it's taking forever +30 minutes to run. 
the code I'm using is:

```
nuc_prof = lapply(levels(nuc$gene_id), function(gene){
  t = nuc[nuc$gene_id==gene, ]
  return(list(gene_id=gene, start=min(t$start), end=max(t$end), pctGC =
              mean(t$pctGC), pct = mean(t$pctAT), cdslength = sum(t$length))) 
})
nuc_prof = do.call(rbind, nuc_prof)
```

I'm certain I'm doing something wrong to slow this down. I haven't waited for it to finish as I'm sure it can be faster. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `tapply` - this might be quicker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since I'm in an evangelizing mood ... here's what the fast `data.table` solution would look like:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(nuc, key="gene_id")

dt[,list(A=min(start),
         B=max(end),
         C=mean(pctAT),
         D=mean(pctGC),
         E=sum(length)), by=key(dt)]
#      gene_id        A        B         C         D   E
# 1: NM_032291 67000042 67108547 0.5582567 0.4417433 283
# 2:       ZZZ 67000042 67108547 0.5582567 0.4417433 283
```

Comment: Holy fudge buckets!!! data.table is awesome! That took about 3 seconds for the whole thing!!!

Comment: @DavyKavanagh -- Hey, mind if Matthew Dowle (`data.table`'s author) uses your testimonial as a blurb for the package? ;)

Comment: Please do. I had started to look into parallel solutions, before data.table was suggested, but immediately stopped upon seeinng it in action. My poor uni-core laptop is useful again!

Comment: I think that congratulations are well in order for the frankly amazingly well written quick start guide and FAQ. Seriously. Where is the button to make all R and bioconductor packages like this one?

Comment: this Q&A are now in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLrdYhizEMg :)

Comment: @jangorecki Fun! Thanks for noting that here.

Answer (score 8):

`do.call` can be extremely slow on large objects.  I think this is due to how it constructs the call, but I'm not certain.  A faster alternative would be the `data.table` package.  Or, as @Andrie suggested in a comment, use `tapply` for each calculation and `cbind` the results.

A note on your current implementation: rather than doing the subsetting in your function, you could use the `split` function to break up your data.frame into a list of data.frames you can loop over.

```
g <- function(tnuc) {
  list(gene_id=tnuc$gene_id[1], start=min(tnuc$start), end=max(tnuc$end),
       pctGC=mean(tnuc$pctGC), pct=mean(tnuc$pctAT), cdslength=sum(tnuc$length))
}
nuc_prof <- lapply(split(nuc, nuc$gene_id), g)
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned - `do.call` has issues with large objects, and I recently discovered exactly how slow it is on large data sets. To illustrate the problem, here's a benchamark using a simple summary call with a large regression object (a cox regression using the rms-package):

```
> model <- cph(Surv(Time, Status == "Cardiovascular") ~  
+              Group + rcs(Age, 3) + cluster(match_group),
+              data=full_df, 
+              x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

> system.time(s_reg <- summary(object = model))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.02    0.03 
> system.time(s_dc <- do.call(summary, list(object = model)))
   user  system elapsed 
 282.27    0.08  282.43 
> nrow(full_df)
[1] 436305
```

While the `data.table` solution is an excellent approach to above it does not contain the full functionality of the `do.call` and I therefore thought that I'll share my `fastDoCall` function - a modification of Hadley Wickhams [suggested hack](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/call-do-call-expression-too-big-td3574335.html) on the R-mailing list. It is available in the Gmisc-package 1.0-version (not yet released on CRAN but you can find it [here](http://gforge.se/packages/)). The benchmark is:

```
> system.time(s_fc <- fastDoCall(summary, list(object = model)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.06
```

The full code for the function is as below:

```
fastDoCall <- function(what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame()){
  if (quote)
    args <- lapply(args, enquote)

  if (is.null(names(args))){
    argn <- args
    args <- list()
  }else{
    # Add all the named arguments
    argn <- lapply(names(args)[names(args) != ""], as.name)
    names(argn) <- names(args)[names(args) != ""]
    # Add the unnamed arguments
    argn <- c(argn, args[names(args) == ""])
    args <- args[names(args) != ""]
  }

  if (class(what) == "character"){
    if(is.character(what)){
      fn <- strsplit(what, "[:]{2,3}")[[1]]
      what <- if(length(fn)==1) {
        get(fn[[1]], envir=envir, mode="function")
      } else {
        get(fn[[2]], envir=asNamespace(fn[[1]]), mode="function")
      }
    }
    call <- as.call(c(list(what), argn))
  }else if (class(what) == "function"){
    f_name <- deparse(substitute(what))
    call <- as.call(c(list(as.name(f_name)), argn))
    args[[f_name]] <- what
  }else if (class(what) == "name"){
    call <- as.call(c(list(what, argn)))
  }

  eval(call,
       envir = args,
       enclos = envir)
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! This also fixes the issue of debug mode printing all the arguments to a function when embedded in the called function